# How to configure Boost in QtCreator project?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, libs

I've tried something like this in my *.pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0"

LIBS += -L/C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0\lib\32-bit -lqtmaind
LIBS += -L/C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0\lib\32-bit -lQt5PrintSupportd
LIBS += -L/C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0\lib\32-bit -lQt5Widgetsd
LIBS += -L/C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0\lib\32-bit -lQt5Guid
LIBS += -L/C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0\lib\32-bit -lQt5Cored
```

But I still get some linker errors (like this one):

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

How does one configure boost paths/libs to get this working?

Comment: If you need more code/anything to be able to help me, just let me know.

Comment: Where have you told Qt to link to the `boost::system` library, and have you really put the Qt5 libraries in the boost folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehh, I was so close. And the mistake was stupid. Syntax one, actually:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Stuff\boost_1_53_0\lib\32-bit" -lqtmaind
and so on...
```

Comment: Ok, only now I realized - I used boost path for qt libs... and for some reason it works... Still, I leave this answer, as it shows the correct syntax.